# How to put products in a category by query

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I need to put products (IDs 10233 to 10247) in a home category (id=2) automatically, in my prestashop (v1.5) shop.

maybe, by sql is easier, no?

**Tables:**

- ps_product_shop - id_product, ...
- ps_category_product (pivot) - id_category, id_product, ...
- ps_category - id_category, ...

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `SELECT` from one table  and then `INSERT` into another. Provide some table structure please, its difficult to answer based on assumptions else the question might be flagged because of low quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ps_category_product (id_category,id_product)
SELECT 2, ps_product_shop.id_product 
FROM ps_product_shop 
WHERE ps_product_shop.id_product > 10232 AND ps_product_shop.id_product < 10248
```

I think something like this could be what you want

Comment: thx for reply. the relationship products-categories is a relationship n to n.

Comment: This is assuming you always want the value "2" as your category

Comment: Let me know if it is what you were looking for or not @MiguelBorges